# Generating random string with T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, random, casting

```
DECLARE @tmp char(1) = '';
SET @tmp = CAST(RAND()*26 AS int)+97;
```

This code doesn't work. The same expression with select works well:

```
SELECT CAST(RAND()*26 AS int)+97;
```

May be my @tmp is declared with a wrong data type?

Comment: Your Variable is `CHAR(1)` use `INT` data type.

Comment: Are you generating random string with characters included or only numbers? In case of numbers you can modify the Datatype of `@tmp` to INT.

Answer (score 2):

I thinkt that you need [`CHAR`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/char-transact-sql) function:

> **CHAR ( integer_expression )**
>
> Converts an int ASCII code to a character.

```
DECLARE @tmp CHAR(1) = CHAR(CAST(RAND()*26 AS int)+97);
SELECT @tmp;
-- z
```

**[Rextester Demo](http://rextester.com/QZZAU21077)**

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring the `@tmp` as `int` instead of `char(1)`:

```
DECLARE @tmp int = '';
SET @tmp = CAST(RAND()*26 AS int)+97;
SELECT @tmp
```

Answer (score 1):

This May help you:

```
DECLARE @tmp nvarchar(38) = '';
SET @tmp = newid()
select @tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tmp varchar(3)= CAST(RAND()*26 AS int)+97;
select @tmp;
```

or you can also trying by changing datatype to int

```
DECLARE @tmp int= CAST(RAND()*26 AS int)+97;
select @tmp;
```